# Avro4k - Exception: Not a named type: "int"

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, avro, azureservicebus

Class:

```
@Serializable
data class User1(
    val id: Int,
    val name: String
)
```

Method:

```
val user = User1(1, "User")
val avroData = Avro.default.toRecord(User1.serializer(), user)
sender2.sendMessage(avroData).getOrThrow()
```

I get this exception when I want to send Avro Record from avro4k to Azure service bus.

`com.digitalchargingsolutions.middleware.servicebus.client.exception.ServiceBusClientException: Not a named type: "int" (through reference chain: com.github.avrokotlin.avro4k.ListRecord["s"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$RecordSchema["fields"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$LockableArrayList[0]->org.apache.avro.Schema$Field["schema"]->org.apache.avro.Schema$IntSchema["aliases"])`

If I send ByteArray all works fine but when I want to send GenericRecord I get the exception.

I try with @AvroAlias but it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you try **Int?** instead of a non-nullable **Int**.

Comment: @DasariKamali
I try but now I get ServiceBusClientException: Not a named type: "null"